# php function call via ajax issue

Tags: php, ajax

I have a home.php through which i send some data which gets inserted into DB, which is done by making an ajax call to another php page, lets say function.php and a unique id is generated against the entry and stored in a variable $id.

When the user leaves the home.php page I want to delete the particular entry that was inserted into the DB, by making another ajax call to same function.php, but the problem is that the $id that was previously generated is lost as function.php is reloaded. Declaring a global in home.php doesn't work.

Any idea how can I store the id, so i can retrieve it, when needed.

Some code would be great.

Abhi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

Put this on your pages to start a session: `session_start()`. Then after you  inserted data into DB do `$_SESSION['sql_insert_id'] = $id` - this is assuming you need just one insert per visitor.

Then when you need to delete from the DB you have the `$id` stored in `$_SESSION['sql_insert_id']`

You can also close the session after the delete with:

```
session_unset($_SESSION['sql_insert_id']);
session_destroy();
```

Comment: i tried using session but when i try to reload the page, it takes a lot of time to reload, dunno y..

Comment: Ok, please post your php in your first question so we can check if there is any other problem. Also add `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);ini_set("display_errors", 1);` to the top of your php for debugging.

Comment: actually the code is very large to be posted here..i will it a few more try n let ya know